# Chaining Grails Plugins?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.3

I am trying to build a Grails plugin that will act as a "master plugin" for a suite of other Grails apps.

I am wondering if it is possible to somehow *chain* plugins together transitively? Pretend that **Plugin A** depends on **Plugin B**, and that **Grails App GA1** uses (installs) **Plugin A**. When the developer does this install of **Plugin A** (the "master") to **Grails App GA1**, they end up installing **Plugin A** as well as **Plugin B**, transitively.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, why, and is there a way to hack this or is there a better way to transitively install plugins in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pretend that Plugin A depends on Plugin B

This means that your Plugin A BuildConfig will have:

```
plugins {
  compile ':pluginB:...'
}
```

When you install Plugin A in your application, Grails will automatically download and install plugin B too.

This is also true for the dependencies block. So **yes**, you can have a plugin that depends on a list of plugins and the application will install all of them. This is the default behavior of using plugins in Grails.

On the contrary, if you want **not** to get **Plugin C** (if there is any which is used by Plugin A), when **Plugin A** is used in the Grails App then you can selectively block the transitivity of pulling Plugin C into the app. Inside **BuildConfig** of Plugin A, you can specify:

```
plugins {
    compile(':pluginC:...') {
        //makes sure Plugin C is not available 
        //when Plugin A is used in the app
        export = false 
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the other side of pulling plugin dependencies. 2 cents. ;)